# How to set condition in style attribute in jsp?

Tags: css, jsp, jpa

Here is the code what i tried.

```
<div style="width:85%;">
<input class="formbutt" value="AddNew" title="AddNew" type="button" 
 style="{(${projectEnvironmentBean.divStyle}=='dipslay:none') ? 'display:block'  :'display:none'}"  id="addNewId" onclick="addnewFn();">
</div>
```

In this code i am checking div-style but unable to get expected result.

Comment: where is `projectEnvironmentBean.divStyle` defined?

Comment: in bean class property 'private String divStyle="display:none";'

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: It is displaying every time ,even i changed property value to display:block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You Just added wrong parentheses.

Try this:

```
<input style="${projectEnvironmentBean.divStyle eq 'dipslay:none' ? 'display:block' : 'display:none'}" />
```

Comment: Please provide more details. Why the user should follow your suggestion?

Comment: @Alberto yes it is working..my mistake is syntax wrong